# how to increase postgres 8.4 shared_buffer in windows 7

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to increase the shared_buffer from 1GB to 2 GB in postgresql.conf file in Windows 7 Machine as I am having 8 GB of RAM but when i make the changes and try to start the postgres service it does not start and when i look into even viewer it gives me following error.

```
 2013-03-18 16:07:41 ISTFATAL:  could not create shared memory segment: 8
 2013-03-18 16:07:41 ISTDETAIL:  Failed system call was MapViewOfFileEx.
```

Please help me out

Answer (score 5):

You're almost certainly running a 32-bit PostgreSQL if you're using 8.4, so the shared memory size is limited by the process's 2GB of total available address space. 32-bit Windows (including 32-bit processes running on 64-bit Windows via Wow64) uses a 2GB/2GB user/kernel split.

The error message means that Pg is trying to allocate more shared memory than the system can map so the system call is failing. You can't really fix this, but you don't need to.

Even 1GB shared_buffers is probably too much for 32-bit Pg on Windows and benchmarks have tended to back that up. You're almost certainly better off keeping `shared_buffers` fairly low and increasing `effective_cache_size` to tell the planner how much disk cache the OS has available to it. You should probably plan an upgrade to PostgreSQL 9.2 for general performance improvements and a longer maintenance lifetime [per the version policy](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/).

Consider posting another question to dba.stackexchange.com with details on WHY you want to increase it. What problem are you trying to solve? If it's a slow query read the [postgresql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql/info) and [postgresql-performance tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info). If you do post a new question, please add a link to it here so people can follow.

Comment: `effective_cache_size` has been there at least since 8.0

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Whoops, teach me to check the docs and not rely on my memory. Thankyou. Corrected.